# Run a command on all subfolders

Tags: command-line, files, directory, wildcards

If you have a series of subfolders (like from `a` to `z`) and want to run a command on each one of them (like `rm *.pdf` or `ls *.pdf`), how do you do that? The "manual" approach would be `cd a`, `rm *.pdf`, or `ls *.pdf`, `cd ..`, `cd b`, ... That seems too complicated, so I believe there must be an easier approach.

Comment: Are there more subfolders than those you shall work on? So e.g. folders a to z shall be considered but subfolders _ and + shall be ignored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try doing this (using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), *brace expansion* & globs):

```
rm -f {a..z}/*.pdf
```

or

```
rm -f [a-z]/*.pdf
```

if your shell lack the *brace expansion* feature.

Contrary to `[a-z]`, `{a..z}` (also supported by ksh93) is not a `glob`, it's brace expansion, it's expanded (before `globs`) regardless of whether files exist or not. That's like `rm -f a/*.pdf b/*.pdf`..., regardless of whether a, b... exist or not. Also note that contrary to `[a-z]` where the range may be locale dependant (like may include `é, ś`...), `{a..z}` only works with byte ranges (and reliably only in the `ASCII` letter ranges, and number ranges)

(Merci Stephane Chazelas for explanations)

Comment: Contrary to `[a-z]`, `{a..z}` (also supported by ksh93) is not a _glob_, it's brace expansion, it's expanded (before globs) regardless of whether files exist or not. That's like `rm -f a/*.pdf b/*.pdf...`, regardless of whether `a`, `b`... exist or not. Also note that contrary to `[a-z]` where the range may be locale dependant (like may include _é, ś..._), `{a..z}` only works with byte ranges (and reliably only in the ASCII letter ranges, and number ranges)

Answer (score 2):

For that particular example:

```
rm [a-z]/*.pdf
```

In any shell.

In the general case, with Bourne-like shells, you could put the list of directories in `$1`, `$2`... with:

```
set a b c foo bar...
```

and then loop over it like:

```
for i do (cd -- "$i" && cmd -- *.pdf); done
```

Though of course you can do both in just one command:

```
for i in a b c foo bar...; do (cd -- "$i" && cmd -- *.pdf); done
```

The point is to use a subshell `(...)` so that `cd` only affects that subcontext.

Answer (score 1):

Use [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find). Something like the following would find all folders (no more than two folders deep), and then execute `rm <pathname>/*.pdf` from the folder:

```
find pathwithsubfolders -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec rm {}/\*.pdf \;
```

In my opinion the best thing to do with commands like these (you know, the ones with potential terrible consequences) is to prepend an 'echo' statement in front of the command you are trying to execute ... just to make sure it looks like what you want before you go pulling the trigger.

Comment: Not rather `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`?

Comment: You quote the ";" but not the "*"?

Comment: By default in bash if a glob does not match anything it is not expanded and you get a '*' this encourages the bad habit of not quoting glob characters.  The `failglob` option changes this behaviour.

Comment: That won't work because globs are expanded by shells, not by `find` or `rm`.

Comment: Hey all thanks, you're all right. I have to escape *s and mindepth does it right. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

find may be the best solution but it is easily possible in shell (bash):

```
GLOBIGNORE=.
for subdir in *; do
  test -d "$subdir" || continue
  cd "$subdir"
  ls *pdf
  cd -
done
```

or even easier

```
ls */*.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one level of directories, you can simply do

```
rm */*.pdf
```

That will delete all the pdf files in all the directories, but nothing else.

In a case like this you may want to review the list of files selected before you do the delete.  To do that try

```
ls */*.pdf
```

And if the list is long enough to scroll off the screen, pipe it through a pager, eg

```
ls */*.pdf | more
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you want to remove all PDF files from the current directory and *all* other subdirectories beneath it, you would do something like

```
find -name "*.pdf" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Two things to note:

1- I have added the `-i` switch to rm so that it prompts you before removing any file in case the `find` is too broad in scope.

2- I highly encourage you to read the `find` man page. It is easily one of my all-time favorites.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) portable solution (for Unix-likes)

```
perl -e '`rm -rf "$_"/*.pdf` for "a" .. "z"'
```

This will removes the subdirectories recursively under `a..z` dirs

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer xargs:

```
find <path> -name '*.pdf' | xargs {ls|rm|etc}
```

This has the benefit of adding grep or other manipulations in the middle of the pipeline, but has the disadvantage of not gracefully dealing with files that have spaces in the file or path name.

Comment: space, but also tab, newline, single quote, double quote and backslash characters.

Comment: In other words, uncommon characters, unless you're sharing a FS with windows.