# How do I execute a command in each subdirectory?

Tags: directory, ln

I'm using Puppet and I need to create symlinks between two folders.
I have around 10 folders with the same structure and I always want to execute my link command in `xx/yy/zz`.

Something like this:

```
ln -s aa/bb/folder_to_link  folders_1_to_x/yy/link_name
```

I tried following [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66451/run-a-command-on-all-subfolders) directions but had no success.

Is there an easy to write command that can accomplish this?

Comment: With `unshare` you can have process-specific mount trees, and so you might `mount --bind` the relationship between the folders of interest for only the life of your command. You can configure that in `fstab`. Do `man mount unshare` if interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution to something like this in puppet is to create a defined type:

```
define folder_link (
 $link_map = $name,
) {
 $link_map_split = split($link_map, ':')
 $origin = $link_map_split[0]
 $link_name = $link_map_split[1]
 $link_path = "/folders_1_to_x/yy/$link_name"

 file { $link_path:
  ensure => link,
  target => $origin,
 }
}


class foo {
 folder_link { ["/aa/bb/folder_to_link:foo", "/cc/dd/folder_to_link:bar"]: }
}
```

This will symlink `/folders_1_to_x/yy/foo` to point at `/aa/bb/folder_to_link`, and `/folders_1_to_x/yy/bar` to point at `/cc/dd/folder_to_link`.

I think it's pretty straightforward how this works, but I can clarify if needed.

Comment: I don't really understand how this would iterate through my directories folders_1_to_x where the symlinks should be created. Since it's possible that some will be deleted or others added I wouldn't want to write an array entry for each library.

Comment: Then you can do it via a shell script, but this is not "the puppet way". The puppet way is to have puppet control the system. If puppet controls the system, then it knows exactly what folders are going to be there. Also note that having puppet run a shell script every time it runs can result in issues, especially if you're using something like puppetdb.

Comment: Okay, I understood my idea was the "easiest and simplest" way to do it but I understand your suggestions. One little question, is it possible to extract variables inside a defined type from another manifest? (both are inside modules)